# Typoscript if/else best practise

Tags: xpath, typo3, typoscript

And still there is me and this Typoscript...

There **may** is an companyId defined in the Project constants, if there is the XML should be filtered to it.

```
[$plugin.xml_path.companyId = '']
  plugin.xml_xpath.conf.xpath.path   = /jobs/job/company
[else]
  plugin.xml_xpath.conf.xpath.path   = /jobs/job/company[@id={$plugin.xml_path.companyId}]
[global]
```

This code works as long as an ID is defined, if none is defined i get one output with marks only.

The Company has about 10 child companys, which should only show the Jobs related to them. But on the Page of the Mothercompany (where no ID Constant is given) all jobs should be listed. Each job is related to 1 child company.

I have read about `stdWrap.ifEmpty` but i have no idea how this would help in my Situation?

Can someone point me to the right direction please?

Comment: Why is this question tagged XSLT?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that `if`, you can do all that in a small XPath expression.

```
/jobs/job/company[@id={$plugin.xml_path.companyId} or @id="" or not(@id)]
```

Explanation:

1. `@id={$plugin.xml_path.companyId}` looks for companies with matching ID
2. `@id=""` looks for companies with empty ID
3. `not(@id)` looks for companies without ID

I wasn't sure about 2 and 3, so I included both. Remove as you want.

---

Update to more specified question:

This is easy to do, too.

```
/jobs/job/company[{$plugin.xml_path.companyId}="" or @id={$plugin.xml_path.companyId}]
```

Comment: this looks awesome, i will remember this for other stuff. But its not what i actually need. [Question Updated] -> The Company has about 10 child companys, which should only show the Jobs related to them. But on the Page of the Mothercompany (where no ID Constant is given) all jobs should be listed.

Comment: Updates my answer, please respecify your question, too.

Comment: I think you still get me wrong (sorry if i am dont able to formulate it better) It doesnt work this way, i just get empty marks again, when die ID constant is empty

Comment: Could you give me the result of the query `1[{$plugin.xml_path.companyId}]`? I'm still quite sure we can do it with a single XPath expression.

Comment: The companyId for example is: 10002345, the resulting XML is way to much (~3000 lines XML per job) to remove all private data. sorry :3

Comment: This query should either return nothing or "1". Nothing if the variable isn't set, "1" if it is.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below typoscript:

```
plugin.xml_xpath.conf.xpath.path   = /jobs/job/company[@id={$plugin.xml_path.companyId}]
[globalVar = LIT: {$plugin.xml_xpath.conf.xpath.path} = ]
plugin.xml_xpath.conf.xpath.path   = /jobs/job/company
[end]
```

The path will be replaced with "/jobs/job/company" if "plugin.xml_xpath.conf.xpath.path" is null.

Comment: This works when i do (plugin.xml_path.companyId = '') in my contance file. Not when there is no companyId. Also just the listing works. When i try to view details its just white. (I was there was proper debugging or i could just open the project to be seen...)

Comment: Can't we initialize :
"plugin.xml_xpath.conf.xpath.path =   "
in the typoscript template ?

Comment: do you mean: plugin.xml_path.companyId = ''? if yes, not its not working. I just get the marks then.

Comment: Have you tried a reg-exp approach? like ... `[globalString = LIT:{$plugin.xml_path.companyId} = /([0-9]+)/]` (must contain at least one digit)